# basic shapes - no subscriber seen in rqt_graph

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, after I went through the ROS Tutorials for beginners, I started to learn simulator - RViz.
when I went through this page: http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes

but at the last step, the basic shapes does not appear in my RViz's UI. it has been solved at my answer.But I have another question, why there is no listerer subscribed to the topic /visualization_marker? if we use rqt_graph to see it?

I run "$ rostopic echo /visualization_marker" and there exists messages updating at 1Hz. I also attached the screen shot below.

But I have another question, why there is no listerer subscribed to the topic /visualization_marker? if we use rqt_graph to see it?

Thank you for any help!

---------below is the info of the teminal running rviz:-------------

exbot@ubuntu:~$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1437095460.714907594]: rviz version 1.10.16
[ INFO] [1437095460.715081304]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.4 (Cthugha)
libGL error: failed to load driver: vboxvideo
libGL error: Try again with LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose for more details.
[ INFO] [1437095460.993503571]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[ INFO] [1437095460.993955591]: OpenGl version: 2.1 (GLSL 1.2).
[ WARN] [1437095595.633391980]: MessageFilter [target=map ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.rviz.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213957/basic-shapes---no-subscriber-seen-in-rqt_graph/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2015-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved!
On the Left Pannel: Display Pannel -> Global Option -> Fixed Frame, Set it to: /my_frame

I set the target frame as /my_frame on the view pannel on the rightside, incorrectly.

THX!

---

Originally posted by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) with karma: 287 on 2015-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on 2015-07-16**:
But I have another question, why there is no listerer subscribed to the topic /visualization_marker? if we use rqt_graph to see it?